# How do I execute a Move script on Aptos using the Rust SDK?

Tags: rust, aptos, move-lang

I want to execute this Move script, e.g. at `sources/top_up.move`:

```
script {
    use std::signer;
    use aptos_framework::aptos_account;
    use aptos_framework::aptos_coin;
    use aptos_framework::coin;

    fun main(src: &signer, dest: address, desired_balance: u64) {
        let src_addr = signer::address_of(src);

        let balance = coin::balance<aptos_coin::AptosCoin>(src_addr);
        if (balance < desired_balance) {
            aptos_account::transfer(src, dest, desired_balance - balance);
        };
    }
}
```

This is calling functions on the [aptos_coin.move](https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core/blob/main/aptos-move/framework/aptos-framework/sources/aptos_coin.move) module, which is deployed on chain. What it does isn't so important for this question, but in short, it checks that the balance of the destination account is less than `desired_balance`, and if so, tops it up to `desired_balance`.

I can execute this Move script via the CLI easily like this:

```
aptos move compile
aptos move run-script --compiled-script-path build/MyModule/bytecode_scripts/main.mv
```

Or even just this:

```
aptos move run-script --script-path sources/top_up.move
```

What I want to know is whether I can do this using the Rust SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to compile the script, as you did above. Imagine you have a project layout like this:

```bash
src/
    main.rs
move/
    Move.toml
    sources/
        top_up.mv
```

You would want to go in to `move/` and run `aptos move compile`, like you said above. From there, you can depend on the compiled script in your code (see below).

With that complete, here is a minimal code example demonstrating how to execute a Move script using the Rust SDK.

`Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "my-example"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
anyhow = "1"
aptos-sdk = { git = "https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core", branch = "mainnet" }
```

`src/main.rs`:

```rust
use aptos_sdk::crypto::ed25519::Ed25519PublicKey;
use aptos_sdk::types::transaction::authenticator::AuthenticationKey;
use aptos_sdk::{
    rest_client::Client,
    transaction_builder::TransactionFactory,
    types::{
        account_address::AccountAddress,
        chain_id::ChainId,
        transaction::{Script, SignedTransaction, TransactionArgument},
        LocalAccount,
    },
};

static SCRIPT: &[u8] =
    include_bytes!("../../move/build/MyModule/bytecode_scripts/main.mv");

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    // Prior to the follow code we assume you've already acquired the necessary
    // information such as chain_id, the private key of the account submitting
    // the transaction, arguments for the Move script, etc.

    // Build a transaction factory.
    let txn_factory = TransactionFactory::new(chain_id);

    // Build a local representation of an account.
    let account = LocalAccount::new(
        AuthenticationKey::ed25519(&Ed25519PublicKey::from(&private_key)).derived_address()
        private_key,
        0,
    );

    // Build an API client.
    let client = Client::new("https://fullnode.mainnet.aptoslabs.com");

    // Create a builder where the payload is the script.
    let txn_builder = transaction_factory.script(Script::new(
        SCRIPT.to_vec(),
        // type args
        vec![],
        // args
        vec![
            TransactionArgument::Address(dest_address),
            TransactionArgument::U64(desired_balance),
        ],
    )));

    // Build the transaction request and sign it.
    let signed_txn = account.sign_with_transaction_builder(
        txn_builder
    );

    // Submit the transaction.
    client.submit_and_wait_bcs(&signed_transaction).await?;
}
```