# How do I execute a Move script with the Aptos CLI?

Tags: move-lang, aptos

Let's say I have a Move script like this:

```
script {
    use std::signer;
    use aptos_framework::aptos_account;
    use aptos_framework::aptos_coin;
    use aptos_framework::coin;

    fun main(src: &signer, dest: address, desired_balance: u64) {
        let src_addr = signer::address_of(src);

        let balance = coin::balance<aptos_coin::AptosCoin>(src_addr);
        if (balance < desired_balance) {
            aptos_account::transfer(src, dest, desired_balance - balance);
        };

        addr::my_module::do_nothing();
    }
}
```

This is calling functions on the [aptos_coin.move](https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core/blob/main/aptos-move/framework/aptos-framework/sources/aptos_coin.move) module, which is deployed on chain. What it does isn't so important for this question, but in short, it checks that the balance of the destination account is less than `desired_balance`, and if so, tops it up to `desired_balance`.

Notice also how it calls a function in a Move module I've defined:

```
module addr::my_module {
    public entry fun do_nothing() { }
}
```

Where do I put these files? Do I need a `Move.toml`? How do I run my script with the CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's run through how to execute a Move script with a step by step example, this should answer all your questions.

Make a new directory to work from:

```bash
mkdir testing
cd testing
```

Setup the Aptos CLI:

```bash
aptos init
```

The CLI will ask you which network you want to work with (e.g. `devnet`, `testnet`, `mainnet`). It will also ask you for your private key (which looks like this: `0xf1adc8d01c1a890f17efc6b08f92179e6008d43026dd56b71e7b0d9b453536be`), or it can generate a new one for you, as part of setting up your account.

From here, initialize a new Move project:

```bash
aptos move init --name my_script
```

Now you need to make a file for your script. So, take the script you created above, and put it in `sources/`, e.g. like this:

```
testing/
   Move.toml
   sources/
      top_up.move
```

In other words, `top_up.move` should contain the script you included in the question.

Now do the same thing with the Move module, leaving you with this:

```
testing/
   Move.toml
   sources/
      top_up.move
      my_module.move
```

Now you can compile the script:

```
$ aptos move compile --named-addresses addr=81e2e2499407693c81fe65c86405ca70df529438339d9da7a6fc2520142b591e
Compiling, may take a little while to download git dependencies...
INCLUDING DEPENDENCY AptosFramework
INCLUDING DEPENDENCY AptosStdlib
INCLUDING DEPENDENCY MoveStdlib
BUILDING my_script
{
  "Result": []
}
```

Note how I use the `--named-addresses` argument. This is necessary because in your code, you refer to this named address called `addr`. The compiler needs to know what this refers to. Instead of using this CLI argument, you could put something like this in your `Move.toml`:

```
[addresses]
addr = "b078d693856a65401d492f99ca0d6a29a0c5c0e371bc2521570a86e40d95f823"
```

Finally you can run the compiled script:

```
$ aptos move run-script --compiled-script-path build/my_script/bytecode_scripts/main.mv --args address:b078d693856a65401d492f99ca0d6a29a0c5c0e371bc2521570a86e40d95f823 --args u64:5
Do you want to submit a transaction for a range of [17000 - 25500] Octas at a gas unit price of 100 Octas? [yes/no] >
yes
{
  "Result": {
    "transaction_hash": "0x655f839a45c5f14ba92590c321f97c3c3f9aba334b9152e994fb715d5648db4b",
    "gas_used": 178,
    "gas_unit_price": 100,
    "sender": "81e2e2499407693c81fe65c86405ca70df529438339d9da7a6fc2520142b591e",
    "sequence_number": 53,
    "success": true,
    "timestamp_us": 1669811892262502,
    "version": 370133122,
    "vm_status": "Executed successfully"
  }
}
```

Note that the path of the compiled script is under `build/my_script/`, not `build/top_up/`. This is because it uses the name of the project contained in `Move.toml`, which is `my_script` from when we ran `aptos move init --name my_script`.

So to answer one of your questions, yes you need a `Move.toml`, you can't currently just execute a script file on its own with the CLI. The compiler needs this determine what Aptos framework to use for example.

See the code used in this answer here: https://github.com/banool/move-examples/tree/main/run_script.

See also how to do this with the Rust SDK instead of the CLI: [How do I execute a Move script on Aptos using the Rust SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74452702/how-do-i-execute-a-move-script-on-aptos-using-the-rust-sdk).

---

P.S. There is a more streamlined way to execute a script. Instead of running `aptos move compile` and then `aptos move run-script --compiled-script-path` separately, you can just do this:

```
$ aptos move run-script --script-path sources/my_script.move --args address:b078d693856a65401d492f99ca0d6a29a0c5c0e371bc2521570a86e40d95f823 --args u64:5
```

This will do both steps with a single CLI command. Note however that there are some major footguns with this approach, see https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core/issues/5733. So I'd recommend using the previous two-step approach for now.