# Aptos SDK - multiple payloads in one transaction

Tags: sdk, blockchain, move, aptos

Sending one payload is easy, for example:

```
let payload1 = txBuilder.buildTransactionPayload("0x1::aptos_account::transfer",[],[to.address(),100000])
  let raw = await client.generateRawTransaction(acc.address(),payload1)
  let signed = await client.signTransaction(acc,raw);
  let res = await client.submitTransaction(signed);
  console.log(res)
  let waiting = await client.waitForTransaction(res.hash);
```

But how do I send more than one payload in a transaction? is it possible in Aptos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, you can only send one payload per transaction. However, if your goal is to do multiple things in a single transaction, that is possible with Move scripts. These posts explain that approach in more detail:

- [How do I execute a Move script with the Aptos CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74627977/how-do-i-execute-a-move-script-with-the-aptos-cli)
- [How do I execute a Move script on Aptos using the Rust SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74452702/how-do-i-execute-a-move-script-on-aptos-using-the-rust-sdk)

Comment: Thanks, I suspected so. sadly Move has many flaws and lacks documentation.